# how to get boundfield value of a gridview in rowupdating event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to pick the databound field value. im getting compilation error saying doesnot contain a definatin for a Cells

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBankDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="gvBankDetails_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvBankDetails_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gvBankDetails_RowUpdating">
                        <Columns>

     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="sl no" DataField="id" />
</Columns>
</Gridview>




protected void gvBankDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        string dtr = ((TextBox)gvBankDetails.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/792388/Why-GridView-RowUpdating-Event-is-not-giving-the-u may this link will help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gvBankDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text
```

index may be different based on column number

Comment: In most cases, the control field (`id` in this Q&A) should be at index 0 for columns and usually not visible at any time.

Comment: Also, in [tag:.net-4.6] Text is not directly accessible from the Cells collection.  Cells collection is now a `Collection<Controls>`, so it will need to be cast to the control in which that cell contains.

Answer (score 2):

to get value of bound field in grid view

```
protected void gvBankDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
 string strName = ((TextBox)gvBankDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
    }
```